# Cannot set session in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, session

I want to set session in jquery, however I'm facing a error as below. I've searched, but I don't find out any solutions to resolve it. Please help me! Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Where did you define `$.session`? Is it a plugin? The error says it all. `$.session` is not defined. So you need to look at that. Can you show your code?

Comment: $.session being undefined probably means you did not correctly reference the jquery.session.js plugin? `<script src="path/to/jquery.session.js"></script>`

Answer (score 1):

$.session is not included in jQuery. You need to use [Jquery Session Plugin](https://github.com/AlexChittock/JQuery-Session-Plugin) to have this functionality. Did you include plugin script file in page ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are talking about `sessioStorage`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   sessionStorage.setItem('compareLeftContent', 'value');
   alert(sessionStorage.getItem('compareLeftContent'));
});
```